# Loading image to ListView

Tags: android

I used this code to retrieve data from PHP and display into a listview.
I put HashMap collections to ArrayList, then insert ArrayList to SimpleAdapter to display on screen.

The problem is If i  put into HashMap an element named "image" and value is image URL, SimpleAdapter do not show the image, it understand it as an String ( Not convert string to image ).

How to solve this problem ?

> JSONObject jsonObject =
>   JSONParser.getJSONObject("xxxxxxx/android_get_places.php");
>               JSONArray jsonArray = null;
>
> ```
>         try {
>             jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("place");
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>         for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
>             JSONObject object = null;
>             try {
>                 object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>
>             try {
>                 String name = object.getString("name");
>
>                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>                 map.put("name", name);  
>
>                 arrayList.add(map);
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList, R.layout.place_item,
> ```
>
> new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.title}));

Comment: Use separate adapter to populate image to the listview..Also Adapter is not responsible to convert your url into image..So please have a separate method to convert url into image and set into your listview..

Comment: This will be the easiest solution for you https://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageDownloader.java?r=3 you can pass ImageView and URL